# How to write parameter name with space in it? Custom Integromat apps

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

Api sends me a response with "Joined at" parameter, and I cant do anything with it because of the space " ", but that paramter is vital for one trigger in my Integromat app.

```
"trigger": {
    "id": "{{item.id}}",
    "date": "{{item.attributes.Joined at}}",
    "type": "date",
    "order": "desc"
}
```

[Response example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V86QC.png)

Comment: You can just do {{item.attributes["Joined at"]}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks to retrieve collection properties, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/other/iml#retrieving-collection-properties).
The expression will look like this: `` "date": "{{item.attributes.`Joined at`}}" ``